# How to pass preexisting sigma instance to sigma.parsers.gexf

Tags: javascript, graph-visualization, sigma.js

In my website I am visualizing a `GEXF` graph with `sigma.js` by using the `sigma.parsers.gexf` to locate the container and load the graph into it.

The `Javascript` code is the same as you can find in the [sigma.js website](http://sigmajs.org/):

```
<script>
    sigma.parsers.gexf(
        path/to/gexfFile.gexf,
        { 
           container: 'sigma-container'
        },
        function(s) {
        }
    );
</script>
```

This works fine, but now I need to be able to load multiple graphs. In order to do this I wanted to create first a `sigma` instance to use it when calling `sigma.parsers.gexf` as explained in this function's [code](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/dd74a6b515a9a93ae7a4264477ee67839ef548a7/plugins/sigma.parsers.gexf/sigma.parsers.gexf.js).

So I create a `sigma` instance before and pass it to the parser function. Problem is, when I try to do so, the graph is simply not drawn and no error is shown in the `firebug` console.

My testing code is as following:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="sigma.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/sigma.parsers.gexf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="myLibrary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="graphSelector" onChange="showGraph(this.value)">
        <option id="defaultValue" value="AENUI" selected>Select...</option> 
        <option value="AENUI">AENUI</option>
        <option value="ICER">ICER</option>
    </select>   
    <div id="foo">
        <div class="sigma-parent">
            <div id="sigma-container" class="sigma-expand"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**myLibrary.js**

```
var actualGraph;

function showGraph(selectedNetwork) {

    var selectedFile;

    if ((typeof selectedNetwork != 'undefined') && (selectedNetwork !== null)) {
        selectedFile = selectedNetwork;
    } else {
        selectedFile = 'AENUI';
    }

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    sigma.parsers.gexf(
        path + selectedFile + '.gexf',
        actualGraph, //if I change this line to  {container: 'sigma-container'} it works
        function(s) {
        }
      );
}



/**
* @method InitForm
*/  
function initForm(){
    actualGraph = new sigma({container: 'sigma-container'});
    var network = document.getElementById("graphSelector").value;
    show(network);  
}



if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initForm, false);
} else {
  window.onload = initForm;
}
```

Additional notes:

- I know I could "solve" this by eliminating the container element from the `DOM` and then recreating it but that is a crude solution I would prefer to avoid.
- I have googled around for examples before posting this questions but could not find one where the `sigma` instance is created and then passed to the parser function. My knowledge on `Javascript` is still a bit limited so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working after asking at the *sigma.js* forums (check this [link](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/358) for more information). The necessary change was to call `refresh()` on my preexisting instance.

This can be done by changing the `showGraph` function to following:

var actualGraph;

```
function showGraph(pathToFile) {

    var selectedFile;

    if ((typeof selectedNetwork != 'undefined') && (selectedNetwork !== null)) {
        selectedFile = selectedNetwork;
    } else {
        selectedFile = 'AENUI';
    }

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if (actualGraph) {
        sigma.parsers.gexf( 
            path + selectedFile + '.gexf',
            actualGraph,
            function(s) {
               s.refresh();                   
            }
        );    
    } else {    
        sigma.parsers.gexf(
            path + selectedFile + '.gexf',
            {container: 'sigma-container'},
            function(s) {
                actualGraph = s;
            }
        );
    }   
}
```